# Improve Django filter preformance for all fields searching special ManyToMany

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-filter, django-filters

I am trying to use django-filter to create a search for all fields. Here is my code:

```
from django.db.models import Q, CharField, TextField, ForeignKey, IntegerField, Func, Value
def get_all_fields_q_object(model, search_value, exclude_fields=None, prefix=None):
    q_object = Q()
    exclude_fields = exclude_fields or []

    for field in model._meta.get_fields():
        if field.name in exclude_fields:
            continue
        lookup_field_name = f"{prefix}__{field.name}" if prefix else field.name
        if isinstance(field, (CharField, TextField)):
            q_object |= Q(**{f"{lookup_field_name}__icontains": search_value})
        elif isinstance(field, ForeignKey):
            related_model = field.related_model
            related_q_object = get_all_fields_q_object(related_model, search_value, exclude_fields=exclude_fields, prefix=lookup_field_name)
            q_object |= related_q_object
        elif isinstance(field, IntegerField):
            try:
                int_value = int(search_value)
                q_object |= Q(**{lookup_field_name: int_value})
            except ValueError:
                pass
        elif isinstance(field, ArrayField):
            q_object |= Q(**{f'{lookup_field_name}__icontains': search_value})
        # # Add more field types as needed...

    return q_object
```

It works for integer, char, foreignkey and array at this moment. But now the model also added ManytoMany fields. I would like to show result based on string icontains. So I handled them like foreignkeyfields:

```
...
elif isinstance(field, ManyToManyField):
            related_model = field.related_model
            related_q_object = get_all_fields_q_object(related_model, search_value, exclude_fields=exclude_fields, prefix=lookup_field_name)
            q_object |= related_q_object
```

Although it works, but the result returns way too slow. Things are:

I assume manytomany fields take time to loop the search

I think about two ways : 1. convert manytomany fields object to a string only use PKname or 2. another search implement to django like SQLAlchemy? But I am not sure in the right direction...Any one has idea to improve it? Thank you!

Comment: The main problem is just that: searching all fields, especially with an `icontains` that can often not be indexed very efficiently, so you performing *linear search*, and not just linear search one one table, which is already a very bad idea, but linear search on *all* related tables.

Comment: Usually `icontains` is also *not* a good way to search. If you the text is "foo bar qux", then `"foo bar" will match, but if it is a tab instead of space for example, or two spaces, we are lost. Usually one creates an index with words or word2vec or something similar, and then thus work with indexed data.

Comment: thanks, not quite sure with this word2vec...do you mean from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVector and using SearchVectorField and GinIndex? I am currently use postgresql, that might be a idea, will try it...

Comment: this will improve the search. Word2vec is something that encodes words (or documents) to a large vector that "summarizes" its content. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word2vec words that thus have a similar meaning are close to each other, whereas words that are very different, should normally map to vectors that are very distant.